# Accessing data generated by an R script with r markdown and knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I am new to R markdown and knitr and haven't found the answer to this question:

I have R scripts where I've written functions and have assigned data to position 1 (.GlobalEnv). How do I access my data and run my functions within R markdown and generate the .html file with knitr?

Here's a trivial example. In a script file I generate:

```
some.x.data<-1:10
some.y.data<-1:10
toy.fn<-function(){
  tot<-some.x.data + some.y.data
  tot
}
```

toy.fn() works in the script file.

My R markdown file contains:

````
---
title: "trivial test"
author: "me"
date: "July 9, 2015"
output: html_document
---


```{r}
plot(some.x.data, some.y.data)
toy.fn()
```
````

When I click knit HTML, I get the following error:

Error in plot(some.x.data, some.y.data) : object 'some.x.data' not found
Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> plot

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 4):

RStudio opens a new R session to `knit()` your `Rmd` file, so the objects in `.GlobalEnv` will not be available to that session (they are two separate sessions), so when you are `knitr`ing `HTML` there is not way to know what `some.x.data`, `some.y.data` and `toy.fn` is.

**Either** you need to recreate them in your `Rmd` file. If you don't want any output just do:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
some.x.data<-1:10
some.y.data<-1:10
toy.fn<-function(){
  tot<-some.x.data + some.y.data
  tot
}
```
````

Full `Rmd`:

````
---
title: "trivial test"
author: "me"
date: "July 9, 2015"
output: html_document
---
```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
some.x.data<-1:10
some.y.data<-1:10
toy.fn<-function(){
  tot<-some.x.data + some.y.data
  tot
}
```
```{r}
plot(some.x.data, some.y.data)
toy.fn()
```
````

**Or**

`knit` manually by yourself: `library(knitr); knit('your_file.Rmd')`

Comment: @ Roman I am having this issue as well. How can you knit the code into the RMD file? thank you!